# SM strings being replaced by ® symbol on iPad device

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4, ios-4.2

I have to show SM(Service Mark) symbol in a label. Whatever way I employ, it is displayed on the device as the ® (Registered) symbol.

I have tried to do this using simply a string:

```
NSString *stringSM =  [otherString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"SM" withString:@"℠"];
```

And using unicode :

```
NSString *stringSM =  [otherString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"SM" withString:@"\u2120"];
```

where otherString is a string received from the web service, containing other information including this SM symbol.